# How to do this with python multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cluster-computing, ray

I frequently use the pattern below to parallelify tasks in python. I do it this way because filling the input queue is quick, and once the processes are launched and running asynchronously, I can call a blocking get() in a loop and pull the results out as they are ready. For tasks which take days, this is great because I can do things like report progress.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
class worker():
    def __init__(self, init_dict,):
        self.init_dict = init_dict

    def __call__(self, task_queue, done_queue):
        for task_args in task_queue.get()
            task_result = self.do_work(task_args)
            done_queue.put(task_result)

if __name__=="__main__":
    n_threads = 8
    init_dict = {} # whatever we need to setup our class
    worker_class = worker(init_dict)

    task_queue = Queue()
    done_queue = Queue()

    some_iterator = [1,2,3,4,5] # or a list of files to chew through normally
    for task in some_iterator:
       task_queue.put(task)

    for i in range(n_threads):
        Process(target=worker_class, args=(task_queue, done_queue)).start()

    for i in range(len(some_iterator)):
        result = done_queue.get()
        # do something with result
        # print out progress stats, whatever, as tasks complete
```

I have glossed over a few detail like catching errors, dealing with things that fail, killing zombie process, exiting at the end of the task queue and catching tracebacks, but you get the idea. I really love this pattern and it works perfectly for my needs. I have a lot of code that uses it.

I need more computing power though and want to spread the work across a cluster. Ray offers a multiprocessing pool with an API that matches that of python multiprocessing. I just can't work out how to get the above pattern to work. Mainly I get:
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance

Does anybody have any recommendations of how I can get results as they are ready from a queue when using a pool, rather than n separate processes?

I appreciate that if I do a massive rewrite, then there are probably other ways to get what I want from ray, but I have a lot of code like this, so want to try and keep changes minimal.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of your code with Ray? It should be able to support this (are you sure you're using the right queue?)